# node_modules: managing import of files without extension

Tags: node.js, npm, import-maps

I have the following setup, trying to establish a no build project using an [import map](https://github.com/WICG/import-maps). I have a **package.json** file and **node_modules** folder with a number of modules generated by a single module install using **npm install xxx**. The importmap has been generated [using](https://github.com/jsenv/importmap-node-module):

```
npx @jsenv/importmap-node-module project.importmap
```

and this works well.

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        ....
        <script type="importmap">
            {
                "imports": {
                    ... the importmap result from npx ...
                }
            }
        </script>
        <script type="module">
            import './wc-test.js';
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <wc-test></wc-test>
    </body>
</html>
```

wc-test.js

Imports a module **xxx** from node_modules via the importmap (this works). However, this module in turn refers to other modules, and sometimes the subsequent modules/files are imported without the extension. eg:

```
import { yyy } from './zzz';
```

which causes an error when the target is actually **zzz.js**.

I imagine that during normal build process this is handled by the [Node.js module resolution algorithm](https://github.com/WICG/import-maps#alternatives-considered). I can change them manually, but is there is easy solution to handle all cases?

I realise that the preferred way would be to build the package but this is not an option in this case - or maybe it is, and that is the direction I should explore.

Any advice?